# Double commutant of matrix algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose we have a matrix algebra $A=\bigoplus_{i} M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ represented on a vector space $\bigoplus_{i} \mathbb{C}^{n_i}\otimes \mathbb{C}^{m_i}$, where $m_i$'s are the multiplicities of irreducible representations. I' trying to show (directly) that the double commutant $A''$ of $A$ is $A$. Obviously, it is enough to show that $A'=\bigoplus_i M_{m_i}(\mathbb{C})$. I did it few months ago, but now I forget how it was done. Any hint or suggestion ?

Comment: Does it really matter what rep of $A$ you have?

Comment: Presented form of the representation is due to the fact that any finite-dimensional faithful representation of such matrix algebra is completely reducible and we can assume that it is of that form.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood what $A'$ was at first.

Comment: Is $A$ finite-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, it is finite-dimensional (we have finite $n_i$'s in the sum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show this for a single summand, $A=M_n(\mathbb{C})$ acting on $\mathbb{C}^n\otimes\mathbb{C}^m$.

Note that the representation $M_n(\mathbb{C})\otimes M_m(\mathbb{C})\to \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}^n\otimes\mathbb{C}^m)$ is an isomorphism.

In general, we have $(A\otimes 1)'=1\otimes B$ inside $A\otimes B$ when $A$ and $B$ are $\mathbb{C}$-algebras with center exactly $\mathbb{C}$. To see this, take a basis $\{b_i\}$ for $B$, so $A\otimes B=\bigoplus_i A\otimes b_i$, then observe

$$ \begin{array}{ll} & \displaystyle \sum_i a_i\otimes b_i \in (A\otimes 1)' \\ \iff & \displaystyle 0=[a\otimes 1,\sum_i a_i\otimes b_i]=\sum_i [a,a_i]\otimes b_i \\ \iff &  0=[a,a_1]=[a,a_2]=\cdots \\ \iff & a_1,a_2,\cdots\in Z(A)=\mathbb{C} \\ \iff & \displaystyle \sum_i a_i\otimes b_i\in 1\otimes B. \end{array}$$